# Flask Api raise an exception keyerror?

Tags: python, api, flask, exception, bad-request

I would like to write a part in my code that checks the content if a key exists . If not the case it raises a personized message keyerror. I'm not sure about which exception to use to raise the message error .

I think the code should be something like this :

```
try: 
    request.files[key]
except badrequestkeyerror as e :
    raise badrequest
```

the message error (f" the {key} doesn’t exists )

Comment: Why not do request.keys.get('your_key', None) and if that is None then you know you don't have the value.

Comment: None is an optional keyword as it defaults to None but you could put request.keys.get('your_key', 'NOTHERE') if you wanted to.